# pyNCO: extract/subset/slice netcdf by dimensions (bbox) in a single command - syntax issues

Tags: python, nco, pynco

With **NCO** I can easily create subset from netCDF file based on given coordinates, e.g.:

```
ncks -d latitude,40.,50. -d longitude,10.,30. in.nc out.nc
```

But I do not know to reproduce such command with **pyNCO**. Analogical syntax could be

```
nco.ncks(input='in.nc', output='out.nc', dimension="longitude,10.,15.", dimension="latitude,45.,50.")
```

but I get an error:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

I found no suitable example in documentation or forums. I managed to do some workaround with single keyword and via tempfile (which is slower) with more lines of code... but I believe there is must be more elegant syntax.

Can anyone provide some guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Python error as you have `(... dimension=..., dimension = ...)` and this results in keyword argument repeated. Unfortunately I have not used PyNCO, but just look at the examples at https://pynco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage. It seems like the correct way to give the limits is by using options and for several dimensions options are in list.

In your case:

```
opt = [
    c.Limit("lat", 45.0, 50.0),
    c.Limit(dmn_name="lon", srt=10.0, end=15.0),
]
nco.ncks(input='in.nc', output='out.nc', options = opt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @msi_gerva. Yes, I have been playing with `options`, that should work. (It took me a while to figure out and declare `import nco.custom as c` ); Anyhow, I am getting `TypeError: 'Limit' object is not iterable`. But obiously that is other problem :- )